# "android" executable not found; please reinstall Android SDK

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

In Appecelerator

When following command executed:

> appc ti setup check

I am getting only one error which is

> "android" executable not found; please reinstall Android SDK

when I check the `/android-sdk/tools/android`

It has executable file there, but still i am  getting error.

And In the console I am getting error

> [ERROR] :  No Android SDK targets found.
>   [ERROR] :  Please download an Android SDK target API level 23 or newer from the Android SDK Manager and try again.

Have reinstalled the SDK many time. Tried all means.

- Can someone pls help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

same problem, workaround is select titanium sdk 6.0.3 instead of 6.0.4 (ti setup > s > 2)

Comment: It didn't help I see only one option when I run the setup command : 1)  6.1.0.GA [active]  C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.1.0.GA
Enter # or SDK name [6.1.0.GA]: 1